# Inserting into Microsoft SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have been using SQL for a bit now but have only recently tried out Microsoft SQL server Express. I have created a database called `test` and a table called `idk`. then I have tried to run the following query

```
USE test;
INSERT INTO idk(Id, Name) VALUES ("1","Name")
```

But that just says

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Invalid column name '1'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Invalid column name 'Name'.

Any help for using SQL with Microsoft SQL server will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the world of _standard_ SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes (') instead of double quotes (") for your values, such as:

```sql
USE test;
INSERT INTO idk(Id, Name) VALUES ('1','Name');
```

Using double quotes is one way to let SQL Server know you are specifying a column name instead of a value. Be careful about the data type for the ID. If it is an integer, SQL Server will convert the value in the query from a string to integer for you but it will be better to not have it as a string unless the data type is a string. For the ID, if it's an integer data type (int, bigint, smallint, or tinyint), then change the query as follows to remove the quotes from the integer value:

```sql
USE test;
INSERT INTO idk(Id, Name) VALUES (1,'Name');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes

```
USE test;
 INSERT INTO idk(Id, Name) VALUES ('1','Name');
```

Also, this might help you out. If you right click on the Table, go to Script Table, and SSMS will generate scripts for you.

[image]